# Instagram not returning pagination object when searching photos by location

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

i'm trying to fetch links from the photos from certain area like [this site](http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map#/37.8697,-122.5901/5000/1443848400-1441256400) does, but i'm not getting the next_url  for the next page of photos, for example i use this:

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=20.881512&lng=-103.83429&distance=5000&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

but i don't get in the response this part:

> {    "pagination":{
>         "next_url":"https#//api.instagram.com/v1/users/319505/media/recent?access_token=TOKEN&max_id=407185589491099817_319505",
>         "next_max_id":"407185589491099817_319505"    },    "meta":{
>         "code":200    },    "data":["omitted"] }

and from the official site i couldn't find and example.
this is the json i get from the response:

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=6fef889a9037081244c7774edd73367b

i understand that some locations doesn't contain that many photos or no photos at all, but i tried with a very turistic place (like Paris,France) to avoid this sort of problem but no result.
This doesn't happen when i try a search with tags, any ideas? is this a bug?

Answer (score -1):

Put &count=-1 at the and of your URL.

Like this: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/(userID)/media/recent/?access_token=(accessToken)&count=-1

Comment: It did not worked for me, got the error "400: Count must be larger than zero." Is there any other work around for the same ? Please let me know.